# R: Use purrr::pmap_df while keeping original data frame in a single pipe

Tags: r, purrr

I want to use `purrr:pmap_df` on a `data.frame` I created, to give me back another `data.frame`. However I want the original `data.frame` "kept" and `cbind`ed to the new `data.frame` in a single pipe. Example:

```
f <- function(a, b, c) {
  return(list(d = 1, e = 2, f = 3))
}

tibble(a = 1:2, b = 3:4, c = 5:6) %>%
  pmap_df(f)
```

This would give me:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  d     e     f
<dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2     3
2     1     2     3
```

But I would like to keep that `tibble`:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 6
  a     b     c     d     e     f
<int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     3     5     1     2     3
2     2     4     6     1     2     3
```

(Silly example but you get what I mean). Any elegant way of doing this in a single pipe?

Comment: `tibble(a = 1:2, b = 3:4, c = 5:6) %>%
  bind_cols(., pmap_df(., f))`

Comment: Thank you, why didn't I think of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to redefine the function, the simplest way is to just use `bind_cols` on the results, using `.` to place the data.frame where you need:

```r
library(tidyverse)

f <- function(a, b, c) {
    return(list(d = 1, e = 2, f = 3))
}

tibble(a = 1:2, b = 3:4, c = 5:6) %>%
    bind_cols(pmap_df(., f))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>       a     b     c     d     e     f
#>   <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     3     5     1     2     3
#> 2     2     4     6     1     2     3
```

You can also use `...` to represent the inputs into `pmap`, which lets you do

```r
tibble(a = 1:2, b = 3:4, c = 5:6) %>% pmap_df(~c(..., f(...)))
```

which returns the same thing.